# conexion c# con postgres

Tags: c#, postgresql

Tengo un problema con esta conexion a pgsql. No sé qué está sucediendo. Coloqué un breakpoint en cada linea de código y entra en todas las líneas pero no me reconoe el usuario, no sé si lo esté haciendo mal o me falte algo.

Ya coloque el `using npgsql;` e hice una clase con la cadena de conexion para llamar solo la cadena y nada. Mi conf de pgsql es exacta, ya intenté todo lo que mis conocimientos tienen. Estoy usando un proyecto de WPF y tambien tengo instalado lo mahapps para darle estilos metro y npgsql lo baje de Nuget, no sé si eso sirva para determinar qué está sucediendo.

Aquí dejo el fragmento de código.

```
private void btnaceptar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool blnfound = false;

    NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432; User Id=postgres;Password=1234;Database = systemBD");
    conn.Open();
    NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("Select * from usuario where cod_usu = '" + txt1 + "' and con_usu = '" + txt2 + "' ", conn);
    NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        blnfound = true;
        modulos form = new modulos();
        form.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    if (blnfound == false)
        MessageBox.Show("Usuario o Contraseña Incorrecta", "Mensaje de Alerta", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    dr.Close();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: "Estoy usando un proyecto de WTF" ??? De casualidad te refieres a un proyecto WPF?

Comment: si, un wpf jeje lo siento no me fije

Comment: estas seguro que tus datos están en   `systemBD` ? no hay ningún error? intentaste hacer la misma query desde el administrador de la base de datos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ha pasado mucho tiempo pero este problema lo resolvi cambiando la version de VS xpress a la completa, pero de la comunidad.. gracias a todos.saludos

Answer (score 4):

Según te entiendo, la aplicación no te saca ningún error de conexión. Simplemente no te está validando el usuario de tu tabla usuario. Si esto es correcto, verifica esta línea de código

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("Select * from usuario where cod_usu = '" + txt1 + "' and con_usu = '" + txt2 + "' ", conn);
```

Acá estas validando dos veces la columna cod_usu con txt1 y txt2. Lo que creo que deberías hacer es validar cod_usu = txt1 y clave = txt2.

Ahora bien, la manera en que estas concatenando el comando

```
"Select * from usuario where cod_usu = '" + txt1 + "' and con_usu = '" + txt2 + "' ", conn);
```

no es muy recomendable pues tu aplicación queda muy expuesta a un ataque de SQL Injection, así que te recomiendo que leas este post http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06 que es de SQL Server pero igual te va a servir para lo que te estoy diciendo.

Answer (score 2):

Fijate si de la siguiente forma funciona, según lo tengo yo configurado en vez de `Server`, uso `HOST` y un par de datos mas:

```
 NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("HOST=127.0.0.1;Port=5432; User Id=postgres;Password=1234;Database = systemBD;TIMEOUT=15;POOLING=True;MINPOOLSIZE=1;MAXPOOLSIZE=20;COMMANDTIMEOUT=20");
```

Comment: ok, muchas gracias intentare en la noche. que el proyecto esta en mi casa cualquier cosa vuelvo por aqui y muchas gracias de verdad

Comment: buenas tardes amigo he intentado colocar la linea que me dijiste pero no, no funciono. de cualquier manera muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Revisa este, es similar:

```
using System;
using Npgsql; //Npgsql .NET Data Provider for PostgreSQL

class Sample
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Specify connection options and open an connection
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(
            "Server=127.0.0.1;User Id=postgres;" + 
            "Password=pwd;Database=postgres;"
        );
        conn.Open();

        // Define a query
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select city from cities", conn);

        // Execute a query
        NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        // Read all rows and output the first column in each row
        while (dr.Read())
        Console.Write("{0}\n", dr[0]);

        // Close connection
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```